# Register custom jdbc driver in sql anywhere

Tags: java, jdbc, sqlanywhere

Is it possible, to register some custom JDBC driver in SQL-Anywhere,
so that it is possible to embed a `table` as `remote table` so that
statements on that table are redirected to that driver? For example
if a `select` gets executed, i want to query data from a webservice and 
return the fir the resut-set. The same things for inserts and so on.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

From the Javadoc of [DriverManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html):

> JDBC 4.0 Drivers must include the file META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver. This file contains the name of the JDBC drivers implementation of java.sql.Driver. For example, to load the my.sql.Driver class, the META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver file would contain the entry:
>
> ```
> my.sql.Driver
> ```

So there's your way of defining custom JDBC drivers. As you want to **not** use the sql anywhere driver in your application (because you'll have your own driver inside the remote part of your setup), there's no need to integrate with sql anywhere there - that's something you have to take care of in your webservices where you'll transform the networked SQL calls to SQL Anywhere calls.

Check out [VJDBC](http://vjdbc.sourceforge.net/) - that already does something similar to what you want to do.

Good Luck